# Possible to declare functions that will warn on unused results in Rust?

Tags: function, return, rust

Does Rust have a way to declare a function, where not using its result will warn - for any types?

Something like GCC's `__attribute__((warn_unused_result));`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of 1.27, `#[must_use]` works for functions too.

---

It appears that the `#[must_use]` attribute is only applicable to `struct`s, `enum`s and `union`s (`union` is not available in stable Rust yet, though): [source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/91f057de35066d0a34102bd0673b56684509b93d/src/librustc_lint/unused.rs#L135). I think this means you can't override it for a function.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you don't mind wrapping said types.

The `#[must_use]` attribute, as answered by @ljedrz, only applies to types. However, in Rust, creating new types is painless *and* has not impact on performance. Therefore, just wrap your type in a `MustUse<T>` type, and have your function resolve this.

```
struct MustUse<T>(T);
```

Comment: A problem with this is you then need API users to be aware of this wrapped type, if for example they took a `usize`, they then need to take a `MustUse<usize>`. I was hoping this could be avoided by applying `#[must_use]` on type aliases, eg: `pub type MustUseUSize = usize;` but the attribute is ignored in this case.

Comment: @ideasman42: Or you just call `.0` on the result of the function, which (1) counts as using it and (2) unwraps it for your users :)

Comment: While a valid answer, overall IMHO this is causing more *damage* to the code then it solves. If adding `.0` on return values is needed all over, *"The Cure Worse Than The Disease"* so to speak, (outside some isolated cases where it may be acceptable)

Comment: @ideasman42: It's only necessary if (1) you want to enforce the value to be used and (2) you are not using `Result`. It seems such a rare situation that I've never had to use it, most of the times I don't care if the caller is not using the return value. The only reason `must_use` was introduced is to remind the caller that the called function might end with an error, which is idiomatically conveyed by the `Result` type in Rust.

Comment: For cases where the only purpose of a function is to calculate a result, this can help avoid mistakes or invalid use. As with many warnings, while not essential, it can help save you time by pointing out logical errors in how a functions used.

Comment: @ideasman42 But what is the logic error here? Not doing anything with the function call, or with the value it returns? Logically, the value, so that's where the constraint should go. --- The other way of doing it would return such newtype, and on the rest of your API, receive that type everywhere it's expected, instead of say, a plain `u32`. This way you can detect "code smells" not by compiler error, but by constructing your newtype by hand.

Comment: Don't see why this should *necessarily* be an attribute of the type, but am also not expert in Rust's type system. Whatever the case, it would be good if this could be done in a way that allows users of functions to have the effects of `must_use` without having to change how they access return values. As with GCC's `warn_unused_result`. If a feature exists but is overly awkward, its a big disincentive to taking advantage of them.

Comment: @ideasman42: This is not a matter of type system (not really) and more a matter of choice. Either or both are possible, so it's up to language designers/compiler writers to make a choice. The main difference between Rust and GCC is that GCC designed a "lint" whereas Rust may have elected to attempt to close the gap toward Linear Types (which would be awesome). One big advantage of Rust approach is that *nearly nobody* has to fiddle with this attribute; whenever you have an error that the caller should be notified of, you use `Result` (with a specific cause) and the caller has to handle it.