# Is there a way to show a warning that a Result is redundant as a return type?

Tags: rust

Is there an attribute like `#[warn(redundant_result_as_return_type)]` to show a warning that [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) is redundant as a return type?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeError();

fn process_some() -> Result<(), SomeError> {
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    process_some().unwrap();
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=48da3521e2e74bb38311d3fdd3eb0a6d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

This code produces no warnings despite the fact that `Result` is not needed as the return type at all.

I've been deciding how to properly implement error handling of a function from the crate used in my project. After digging into the function implementation, it turned out that no errors are generated.

Since then, I want to prevent such cases in my own code. Ideally it would be great to get such warnings from inside of imported crates too, when utilizing methods with redundant `Result`s, but as far as I understand such checking is impossible for used crates without adjusting their code.

The question is in some way the opposite of [Possible to declare functions that will warn on unused results in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369402/possible-to-declare-functions-that-will-warn-on-unused-results-in-rust).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such warning, either in the compiler or in [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy). You could submit an issue to Clippy suggesting they add it, of course.

---

I challenge that this is a common occurrence or even one that is actually a problem. Even if it was, I'd believe such a warning will have many disadvantages:

- I use this pattern to scaffold out functions that I'm pretty sure will return an error once I've implemented them.
- A method that is part of a trait cannot change the return type.
- You might be passing the function as a function pointer or closure argument and the return type cannot be changed.
- Changing the return type breaks API backwards compatibility, so you have to wait until a major version bump.